# Limit/Integration in heat equation

Tags: integration, limits, partial-differential-equations

While studying heat equation from *PDE by L.Evans*, I came across the following limit which I'm not able to prove.

For $n>=1, \delta >0$ ,

$lim_{t \to 0+}  \;\;{1 \over t^{n/2}}\;\;\int_{\delta}^{\infty}{e^{-r^2/16t} r^{n-1}}dr = 0$

My approaches have been:

1) take the series expansion of the integrand.

2) use the exponential integral.

But it keeps getting complicated. I want to know if there is a better way to attack this problem .